# cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically

Tags: drop-down-menu, lambda, kendo-ui

I am trying to add a change event to my kendo dropdownlist but I am getting an error 'cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically' at the event line.

```
                        @( Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                               .Name("DataType")
                               .DataTextField("Text")
                               .DataValueField("Value")
                               .BindTo(ViewBag.DataType)
                               .Events(e => e.Change("OnSearchTypeChange"))
                              )
```

Any thoughts, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this issue was to include a kendo type library in the razor view. The compiler was not recognising the function without this reference hence it was complaining about the lambda expression.

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a Type for ViewBag.DataType. Try casting like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("DataType")
    .DataTextField("Text")
    .DataValueField("Value")
    .BindTo((YourDataType)ViewBag.DataType)
    .Events(e => e.Change("OnSearchTypeChange"))
)
```